# Inline elements in contact form, problem on validation

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

I have a problem with keep the form components in one line during validation.

Code:

```
<label class="mynumber">Number [text* mynumber maxlength:8]/XYZ</label>
```

After validation part "/XYZ" escapes under the validation message. How to keep it in one line?

Form preview
[image: Form]

After validation
[image: Form after]

The form, unfortunately, generates information about validation which is displayed right for the INPUT.

```
<label class="mynumber">
Number 
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap mynumber">
<input type="text" name="mynumber" value="" size="40" maxlength="8" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="wpcf7-f121-p122-o1-ve-mynumber">
<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip" aria-hidden="true">The field is required.</span>
</span>
/XYZ
</label>
```

Comment: That is happening because the width of the parent element is not enought to hold that elements in one line.

By the way if you can provide more of your html and css code of that part it would be pretty helpful for us

Comment: @Castle there is no additional code. The page container have 100%. I only styled this input to 200px, because I need it short. I added the code, generated by the form after validation.

Comment: set the tip to position absolute

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out in the comments by [Howard E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821467/howard-e), you can set the CSS style of the error msg to,

```
.wpcf7-not-valid-tip{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

if you want to set this only for the `mynumber` field, then

```
span.mynumber > .wpcf7-not-valid-tip{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```